# linear span of subspace

Tags: vector-spaces, span

we have the following subspace over $\mathbb{R}$ $$M = \{ A \in M^{{n\times n}} | A = -\overline{A} \}$$
I found that it is a subspae and now I need to find the linear span of it.
how can I calculate the linear span of a subspace?

Comment: What do you mean by $\bar{A}$?

Comment: @timon, it's useless here it was used when the group was over $\mathbb{C}$ from the previous question I had. so I've edited it. thanks.

Comment: $A = -A $ give you $A = 0$. So $M= \{0\}$.

Comment: I think your previous question makes sense if you replace the word group by subspace.

Comment: @timon changed back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a subset is already a subspace, then it equals it own span (which is defined as the smallest supspace containing it)

Answer (score 1):

First note that for every matrix $A=(a_{j,k})$ satisfying $A = -\bar{A}$, gives us, $a_{j,k}= -\bar{a_{j,k}}$ i.e. $a_{j,k}$ is purely imaginary. So $a_{j,k}= i b_{j,k}$, where $b_{j,k}$ is a real no. Now consider the set

\begin{align}
B = \{ iE_{j,k}| j,k = 1,2,...,n\}
\end{align} where $E_{j,k}$ is the elementary matrix whose $(j,k)$th entry is $1$ and all others entry are zero.

Now It is straight forward to verify that $B$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$ and form a basis for the given subspace. Clearly dimension of the subspace is $n^2$.